# C++: Ray Tracer causing out of memory errors -- due to repeated calls to 'new'?

Tags: c++, raytracing

This is a pretty broad question, so I hope it fits the guidelines loosely for S/O questions.

Basically, I'm writing a Ray Tracer that takes input from a scene file. Right now, for each new triangle/sphere defined in my scene file, I do the following in C++ (hopefully the code is self explanatory):

```
GeometricPrimitive* primitiveToAdd = new GeometricPrimitive();
Triangle* triangleToAdd = new Triangle(ax, ay, az, bx, by, bz, cx, cy, cz);
BRDFCoefficients *brdfToAdd = new BRDFCoefficients();
Color* kaToAdd = new Color(kar, kag, kab);
Color* kdToAdd = new Color(kdr, kdg, kdb);
Color* ksToAdd = new Color(ksr, ksg, ksb);
Color* krToAdd = new Color(krr, krg, krb);
brdfToAdd->ka = *kaToAdd;
brdfToAdd->kd = *kdToAdd;
brdfToAdd->ks = *ksToAdd;
brdfToAdd->kr = *krToAdd;
brdfToAdd->sp = ksp;
Material* materialToAdd = new Material();
materialToAdd->constantBRDF = *brdfToAdd;
primitiveToAdd->material = materialToAdd;
primitiveToAdd->shape = triangleToAdd;
aggregatePrimitive.addPrimitive(primitiveToAdd);
```

(aggregatePrimitive is a global variable that has a 
`std::vector<GeometricPrimitive*>` listOfPrimitives;)

The ray tracer works fine on small examples, but when I try to fire up some more complicated examples from an .obj file, my computer runs it for a few minutes and then gets an out-of-memory error. I've also spun up a 60GB RAM EC2 instance and run the ray tracer on that, and it still runs out of memory.

At first I assumed that it was just because the ray tracer was too slow and it was literally taking up too much memory. But could it be something else? Specifically the repeated calls to new? (I'm not exactly sure what the precise consequences of dynamically allocating memory in this situation would be.) Seems a bit fishy that a 60GB RAM EC2 instance wouldn't work...

Again, I realize this is a pretty broad and non-specific question, but any ideas?

Comment: I assume you call delete at some point to free those memory. What OS are you running 32/64bit? Is the exectuable 32/64bit? Any other information you can provide?

Comment: probably you leak them all?

Comment: Also keep track of the size of listOfPrimitives, if it's incredibly large just before the crash, you'll know your program is genuinely using/leaking that memory and it's not an external problem.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Okay, so all of the primitives actually SUCCESSFULLY get added to my `aggregatePrimitive` (one .obj file had like 5000 triangles defined in it.) What happens in my Ray Tracer is that after the shapes are added to the `aggregatePrimitive`, then there's the regular ray tracing loop that says `for each pixel in image plane, process pixel and find intersection of ray with shapes`. It actually GETS to this `for` loop and processes thousands of pixels before the program crashes. Does this change anything?

Comment: Also, right now, after all of the colors of each pixel are committed (and right before I try to write the colors to a file), I call the following loop, which I see in itself has problems:

`// Deallocate memory
   for (std::vector<GeometricPrimitive*>::size_type i = 0; i < aggregatePrimitive.listOfPrimitives.size(); i++) {
    delete aggregatePrimitive.listOfPrimitives[i];
   }`.

Comment: Clearly I don't delete the `Color` pointers, the `BRDFCoefficients` pointer, and the `Material` pointer, which I should do. However, due to the comment I posted above, is this really the reason my program is crashing?

Comment: @RyanYu: You said you get memory exhaustion errors. And, yes, of course if you don't free resources you will exhaust memory. So that's why your program crashes...

Comment: Don't use `new` like this. This isn't Java.

Answer (score 2):

> Specifically the repeated calls to new?

**YES!**

You did not free *any* of those resources.

To me it looks like you should be avoiding `new` entirely. For example:

```
Color kaToAdd(kar, kag, kab);
```

No need for dynamic allocation here, surely.

If you *know* you need dynamic allocation, then fine, but be sure to `delete` those resources when you're done with them, preferably through a wrapper such as `std::unique_ptr`.